# Swift - NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nskeyedunarchiver

```
var objects: AnyObject? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
```

How to turn objects into NSMutableArray ? I archived NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just downcast the result to `NSMutableArray`:

```
if let objects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? NSMutableArray {
    // ...
} else {
    // failed
}
```

If the archived object is an (immutable) `NSArray` then you have to create a mutable
copy:

```
if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? NSArray {
    let objects = NSMutableArray(array: array)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov: Strange, I tested it. Are you sure that the archived object is a *mutable* array? Does it work with `as? NSArray` ?

Comment: ops No it wasn't NSMutableArray.. sorry my mistake it works :)

Comment: Seems to me like casting to `[AnyObject?]` would be more "Swifty". I'm interested in what happens when you set an NSMutableArray to a `let` since you cannot change a `let`.. therefore making it a an NSArray

Comment: @DougMead: NSMutableArray is a *reference type*. Even if you assign it with `let`, you can modify the referenced (mutable) array. It does not make it an NSArray.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'm confusing syntactic sugar with actually assigning an NSMutableArray reference. I definitely remember seeing that let creates NSArrays and var creates NSMutableArrays in swift.. Am I correct in my assumption?